# How to convert number to string for Web Applications in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I created a simple web application where the user enters a number and it gets calculated into different currencies. The problem I found is that for the number to be displayed back out it first needs to be converted to a string. Normally, if it wouldn't be a web application I would just do `number->string x` but in this case, it does not want to work, or at least I'm doing something wrong.

My code:

```
#lang racket

(require web-server/servlet
         web-server/servlet-env)

(define (page request)
  ;; extract the key value if present
  (define bindings (request-bindings request))

  ;; print entered currency when available
  (cond ((exists-binding? `amount bindings)
         (define (mynumber) (extract-binding/single `amount bindings))
         (define usd (lambda (mynumber) (* mynumber #i1.25)))
         (define eur (lambda (mynumber) (* mynumber #i1.14)))
         (response/xexpr
          '(html (head (title "Currency Exchange"))
                 (body
                  (h1 "Currency Exchange")
                  (div ((class "amount"))
                       (p "entered amount" ,mynumber)
                       (p "amount in USD: " ,usd)
                       (p "amount in EUR: " ,eur))
                  ))))

        ;; If there is no currency entered
        (else
         (response/xexpr
          '(html (head (title "Currency Exchange"))
                 (body
                  (h1 "Currency Exchange")
                  (p "enter currency in GBP:")

                  (form
                   (input ((name "amount")))
                   (input [(type "submit") (value "Calculate")]))
                  ))))
        )
  )

(serve/servlet page
               #:port 8080
               #:listen-ip #f
               #:servlet-path "/currency")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly answering your question, but here are a few mistakes I see:

1.

```
(define (mynumber) (extract-binding/single `amount bindings))
```

Should probably be:

```
(define mynumber (extract-binding/single 'amount bindings))
;; OR
;; (define mynumber (string->number (extract-binding/single 'amount bindings)))
```

There's no use in creating a procedure in this case. A simple definition does the job.

Use quote instead of quasiquote when you are not using unquote.

2.

```
(define usd (lambda (mynumber) (* mynumber #i1.25)))
(define eur (lambda (mynumber) (* mynumber #i1.14)))
```

Should probably be:

```
(define usd (* mynumber 1.25))
(define eur (* mynumber 1.14))
```

Again, there is no need to create a procedure, because all you want to do is multiply two numbers.

The `#i` (inexact number) prefix is redundant, because real numbers without an exactness specifier are usually inexact by default ([details here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=%23i#%28idx._%28gentag._12._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29)).

3.

```
(response/xexpr
          '(html (head (title "Currency Exchange"))
                 (body
                  (h1 "Currency Exchange")
                  (div ((class "amount"))
                       (p "entered amount" ,mynumber)
                       (p "amount in USD: " ,usd)
                       (p "amount in EUR: " ,eur)))))
```

You can fix this by using `quasiquote` (i.e. `` ` `` [backtick]) instead of `quote` (i.e. `'`), because you are using `unquote` (i.e. `,`).

Use quasiquote instead of quote when you are using unquote.